# Nelder-Mead simplex (fminsearch) and crossvalidation (cvpartition) with a nested function approach - Valid?

Tags: svm, optimization

I have a binary classification problem with a somewhat balanced training set ( 665 TP 568 TN). SVM is the classifier of choice, and I am trying to optimize the hyperplane parameters $c$ and $g$ using Nelder-Mead simplex (fminsearch) and cross validation following a certain scheme (see below).

I have a feeling that this approach is biased, but I cannot really tell how to conduct it in a better way. Is the codeflow consistent in general? (as I am nesting anonymous functions) What would be a good $c$ and $g$ range that can set in the fminsearch options?

Does it make sense to create the CV partitions once in the beginning, or should I reinit them on each new fminsearch run?

```
%create cross fold partitions
c = cvpartition(classes,'kfold',kFold);

%minimization function (z = [c,g])
%where minperf is a function doing a crossvalidation with current parameterset summing
%missclassificationrate over all folds (see at bottom)
minfn = @(z)minperf(z,meas,classes,c,opt_mode);

Loop for X optimization rounds and keep best setup

%unconstraint optimization using nelder mead simplex
%to avoid being stuck in local minimum this step is repeated X times and best
%parameters are stored 
[searchmin fval] = fminsearch(minfn,randn(2,1));



%after finding C and r a final cross validation is performed for performance 
%estimation of final model
finfun = @(xtr,ytr,xte,yte)confusionmat(yte,cross_svm(xtr,ytr,xte,z(1),z(2)));

cm = crossval(finfun,meas,classes,'partition',c)
cm = reshape(sum(cm),2,2)

%the final model is constructed using all data and optimized parameters..
svmStruct = svmtrain(meas,classes,'Kernel_Function','rbf','Autoscale',true,...
   'rbf_sigma',z(1),'boxconstraint',z(2));
```

Somehow I have a feeling there is a bias.  Using blind data, performance is worse than what would be expected from the cross validation.  Any suggestions for a good range I can set for $c$ and $r$ as parameters for fminsearch?

```
 %optmode just decides which measure is used for performance evaluation (e.g mcr)
    function out = minperf(z,meas,classes,c,opt_mode)

            fuun = 

@(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest)perf_clsf(cross_svm(xtrain,ytrain,xtest,exp(z(1)),exp(z(2))),ytest,opt_mode);

        out = crossval(fuun,meas,classes,'partition',c);

        out = sum(out)/length(out);

    end
```

UPDATE:
Thanks for the answer, i recall out was a vector and not a single value..

my perf_cls simply returns this : out = sum(yte ~= ypredte);

More remarks on this?

UPDATE2:
I found that mathworks is exactly proclaiming this method.. maybe they should add the bias remark.. http://www.mathworks.nl/help/bioinfo/ug/support-vector-machines-svm.html#bs3tbev-16

UPDATE3:
Here a final remark, Varma and Simon compared a similar CV approach with another nested CV optimization revealing the bias of the above approach and showing the benefit of using the nested version: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1397873/

Comment: I think your error is in summing 'out' and dividing by the length - if you are using crossval to calculate MCR, there is no need to sum and divide and the output of crossval will be a the mean MCR across folds, though it is not clear to me exactly what 'perf_clsf' does but I asume it is a sub-function training and testing the SVM

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a bias, because you have directly optimised the cross-validation error, so it will give an optimistic estimate of generalisation performance.  Lie all estimators, the error of the cross-validation estimate of the test error has two components, the bias (the error caused by the CV error being systematically wrong) and the variance (the error due to the peculiarities of the sample of data on which it is evaluated).  CV is (approximately) unbiased, so we don't need to worry about that too much.  However it has a finite variance, which means that you would get a slightly different result each time if you evaluated the CV estimate over a different sample of data from the same underlying distribution.  If you directly optimise the CV, you will to some extent be optimising it in ways that depend on the particular sample on which it is evaluated, but this is essentially just meaningless noise.

This is a very common issue in machine learning, but perhaps not as widely appreciated as it should, so I wrote a paper about it, which you can find here:

G. C. Cawley and N. L. C. Talbot, Over-fitting in model selection and subsequent selection bias in performance evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 2010. Research, vol. 11, pp. 2079-2107, July 2010. ([www](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html))

The problem gets worse if you have many hyper-parameters to choose, and can easily result in ending op with an "overtuned" model that generalises quite badly.